# drag drop unlimited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am using JQuery and I wanted to know howto create a drag and drop, BUT, the drag element has like an unlimited supply. I can keep on dragging out an copy of the drag element over and over again. Any ideas?

Comment: Without relevant code to show what you're doing, not in the slightest.

Comment: Did you try [jquery-ui drag and drop](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)

Comment: I just have a simple query draggable set up. I don't think its that relevant.

Comment: To be honest, I just placed several divs one on another to try and simulate the effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean cloning? Then try this: http://www.placona.co.uk/166/javascript/a-more-elaborated-jquery-drag-drop-cloning/